# Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object using str_get_html()

Tags: php, domdocument

In the script below, I'm getting an error when the URL is not found or reports 404...

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object

How can I code around it?

```
function processPage(){

    $this->html = scrapePage($this->url);

    $dom = str_get_html($this->html);

    $metakws = $dom->find('meta[name=keywords]'); //ERROR OCCURS HERE WHEN URL NOT FOUND

    //etc...

    }
```

Comment: It's hard to know what's failing with just that piece of code. The error is clear enought tought, `$dom` doesn't have the property `find()`.

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I had a programmer write this on the quick. Can any of these be included as a php include like SimpleHtmlDom? Its taking about 10 seconds per search. I'd expect those to be faster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for

```
if (!$dom) { /*Error*/ }
```

Or

```
if (!is_object($dom)) { /*Error*/ }
```